# Background Size Not Working

Tags: html, css

I put a background but the size was way smaller then I expected. I even changed the size but it still was the same size. Here's what I wrote:

```
<div style="background:#7FA6B3;width:1350px;height:400;text-align:center">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing the "height:400px;"

or you can use padding:400px

(em, %, or inches or other size)

Comment: Thanks, it was because i forgot to put "px".